# Uwsgi environmental variables

Tags: uwsgi

I,m stuck with my flask uwsgi application, which cannot see environmental variables, i put those in .bash_profile file, like 
export key="variable", and typed *source ~/.bash_profile*, but no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use `python-dotenv`, add your environment variables to a `.env` file and then, in your `config.py` or whatever you use for loading environment variables, import it and call `load_dotenv()`. Then you can use
`variable = os.getenv('variable_declared_in_dotenv')` to load it.

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer, will try to do this.

Comment: it would help to specify things like: the .env goes on the root directory, the format it follows, that you should do `from dotenv import load_dotenv`... otherwise good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

`[uwsgi]`

`base = /var/www/html/poopbuddy-api`

`chdir = %(base)`

`app = app`

I'm not sure exactly what `chdir` does, but I think it sets the default path to the root folder of the application, from there, load_dotenv() now works for me.